# SwiftUi initialize the main struct in a class

Tags: class, struct, swiftui, initialization

I can't seem to be able to initialize the fest var below. I am getting the following error when doing so:

'self' used in property access 'fest' before all stored properties are initialized

My struct is:

```
struct Fest: Codable {
    let days, year: String
    let shows: [Show]
}

struct Show: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID() 
    let showName, stageName, description: String
    let times: [Int] 
    let isFavorite, oneNight: Bool
}
```

My class is:

```
class FestivalData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var fest: Fest
    @Published var shows: [Show] = []
    
    init() {
        self.fest = fest
    }
    
    func addShow (_ show: Show) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
            shows.append(show)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean to be capturing `[self]` in the closure and then not actually using it? Perhaps you mean `self.shows.append`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, but this still doesn't give me what I am trying to do.
in the class I need to be able to add data to the fest var. The fest var is the main part of the data struct that needs to be updated. I was using `@Published var shows: [Show] = []` because that works.

```
fest.days = stringOfDays
fest.shows.append(shows)
```

similar to using the `addShow` function.

in my ContentView I have:
`@StateObject var festivalData = FestivalData()` and I get the following error:
Missing argument for parameter 'fest' in call

I don't have to put a parameter for the other published var.

Comment: Sorry, I missed this because it should have been an edit to your question or a comment on my answer (this, in it self, is not an answer). Yes, you would need to pass a `Fest` to `FestivalData` in its initializer. I'm not quire sure about what the problem is with mutating `fest` -- it's a `var`, so you should be able to do the code you referenced adding days and shows. I think I must be missing an important part of the equation, but it's just not clear to me what that is yet.

Comment: Sorry about posting in the wrong spot. I have been pulling my hair out trying to get this to work. The func addShow works as is, but what I am really trying to do is append the array of shows to the Fest struct: fest.shows.append(shows) shows is being populated, but needs to be added to the fest.